# Sum of consecutive numbers with a rounded multiplier

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know full well that the sum of the integers from $1$ to $n$ is $\frac{n * \left (n+1\right )}{2}$ but I need a formula that works for the rounded multiples of $\frac{9}{7}$ the integers from $1$ to $n$.

e.g.

| $n$ | $\lfloor\frac{9}{7}n\rceil$ | cumulative sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 8 |
| 4 | 5 | 13 |
| 5 | 6 | 19 |
| 6 | 8 | 27 |

any ideas?  i don't even know what to search for so i don't know how to tag this question.

Comment: The hard part is of course finding a formula for $\lfloor\frac{9}{7}n\rceil=n+\lfloor\frac{2}{7}n\rceil$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re adding all the numbers up to $\left\lfloor\frac97n\right\rceil$ except those with remainders $2$ and $7$ modulo $9$. So you have $\frac{\left\lfloor\frac97n\right\rceil\left(\left\lfloor\frac97n\right\rceil+1\right)}2$, but you need to subtract the missing numbers. There are $\left\lfloor\frac{n+5}7\right\rfloor$ missing numbers with remainder $2$, and they add up to $2\left\lfloor\frac{n+5}7\right\rfloor+9\cdot\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{n+5}7\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n+5}7\right\rfloor-1\right)}2=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{n+5}7\right\rfloor\left(9\left\lfloor\frac{n+5}7\right\rfloor-5\right)}2$, and similarly there are $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}7\right\rfloor$ missing numbers with remainder $7$, and they add up to $7\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}7\right\rfloor+9\cdot\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}7\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}7\right\rfloor-1\right)}2=\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}7\right\rfloor\left(9\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}7\right\rfloor+5\right)}2$, so the sum is

$$
\frac12\left(\left\lfloor\frac97n\right\rceil\left(\left\lfloor\frac97n\right\rceil+1\right)-\left\lfloor\frac{n+5}7\right\rfloor\left(9\left\lfloor\frac{n+5}7\right\rfloor-5\right)\right)-\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}7\right\rfloor\left(9\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}7\right\rfloor+5\right)\;.
$$

Comment: that's great for me, since it's 9/7 and i can filter out the missing number's cumulative sums.  i wonder if there is a more generic solution 